# web service: java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 500 for URL

Tags: java, web-services, cxf

i'm trying to use a cxf web service. i have a java sample in intelliJ and when i run it, every thing is ok. but when i try to invoke web service in a java web project(Struts2 and spring framework) i got this exception. every thing is same in both code. and both are running in same client.

Can any body tell me what went wrong ?

```
org.apache.cxf.interceptor.Fault: Could not send Message.
at org.apache.cxf.interceptor.MessageSenderInterceptor$MessageSenderEndingInterceptor.handleMessage(MessageSenderInterceptor.java:64)
at org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain.doIntercept(PhaseInterceptorChain.java:236)
.
.
.
`Caused by: java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 500 for URL: http://servicebus......
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection$10.run(Unknown Source)
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection$10.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
`.
 .
 .
 .
 .
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 500 for URL: http://servicebus......
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream0(Unknown Source)
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(Unknown Source)
at java.net.HttpURLConnection.getResponseCode(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.HTTPConduit$WrappedOutputStream.handleResponseInternal(HTTPConduit.java:2081)
... 111 more
```

code i used is below:

```
        CustomsDebtService customsDebtService = new CustomsDebtService();
    CustomsDebt debtWebService = customsDebtService.getCustomsDebtPort();
    java.util.Map<String, Object> ctx = ((BindingProvider) debtWebServicePort).getRequestContext();
    ctx.put("ws-security.signature.properties", "keystore.properties");
    ctx.put("ws-security.encryption.properties", "truststore.properties");
    ctx.put("ws-security.encryption.username", "servicebus.ecogif.XX");
    ctx.put("ws-security.asymmetric.signature.algorithm", "http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmldsig-more#rsa-sha256");
    ctx.put("ws-security.callback-handler", "externalWebService.XXX.newDebts.CertificatePasswordCallbackHandler");
    PersonDebtInquiryResult personDebtInquiryResult;

        if (Empty.isNotEmpty(iricaDebtsInquiry.getNationalCode()))
        {

            personDebtInquiryResult=debtWebService.personDebtInquiryByNationalID("000000001");
        }
```

exception occurs in last line.
all addresses are correct.

also there is some .jks file for config that i put them in ctx (in code). what is the correct path of this file so that can be understand by code. is it possible that problem occurs because of wrong path?

Comment: It's so dificult to help if we can't see the code

Comment: code in both project is same, but one is web project and another is not. can this caused for miss configuration  (may be in tomcat,...) ? or may be for lack of libs (used in run time) in my project?

Comment: HTTP status code 500 :usually means that the webserver code has crashed the server  doesn't like the input param

Comment: you means that problem is for message i send?

Comment: Your request might be missing some parameters

Comment: all parameter are set in same way. and in sample when i remove config i get another exception except error 500. can it be because of calling in web project?

Comment: A running application is so much more than just code. Please share with us much more details on your two setups (environment & code too) if you need help.

Comment: i add my code in question. if more things is needed please note .